# regex validation with android Java Phone , Email, Date

Tags: java, regex, validation, email, phone-number

Can someone help me with these regex validation with android Java :
Date :  `yyyy-mm-dd`
Phone : `(0999)-999-99-99`
Email : `abc@gmail.com`

Comment: don't use regex to validate dates. Searching the site  will give you the answers.

Comment: Don't use regex to validate phone numbers either (and probably not even emails) unless you have very specific rules for the emails/phones you will accept

Comment: ok.. i will use Edittext with datepicker and disable Edittext..

Comment: So no validation.. doesn't sound a very good idea..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since API Level 8 and above, Android has patterns for email, phone number e etc; that you can use. For example:

```
private boolean isValidEmail(CharSequence email) {
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
        return Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches();
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean isValidPhoneNumber(CharSequence phoneNumber) {
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(phoneNumber)) {
        return Patterns.PHONE.matcher(phoneNumber).matches();
    }
    return false;
}
```

For more details, see: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Patterns.html

Hope this helps.